# Are there any API to get Facebook profile URL by using the phone number?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a phone number, how can I get a user ID on Facebook so that I can go to the user profile by https://www.facebook.com/user_id

In Vietnam, there is a page can do that: https://atpsoftware.vn/finduid/

Comment: There is no API for that. Any external services providing this, must be scraping user profiles or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, there is no API for it. Scraping is not allowed, and the phone number would need to be public anyway to make that work.